# Do I really have to create two versions of my variable just to use objective-c blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, objective-c-blocks

There are lots of questions regarding blocks and retain cycles... They led me to put together the following code:

```
- (void)promptNewName {
    DTAlertView* prompt = [[DTAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Name" message: @"foobar"];
    prompt.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [prompt addCancelButtonWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil) block: ^{}];
    __weak DTAlertView* weakPrompt = prompt; // need a weak reference to the prompt for the block
    [prompt addButtonWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Update",nil) block: ^{
        self.valve.name = [weakPrompt textFieldAtIndex:0].text;}];
    [prompt show];
}
```

My question is, is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this? `DTAlertView` is a "block aware* version of `UIAlertView`. But if I have to do extra work to use the blocks, it seems it's not as desirable.

Comment: Without knowing the internals of `DTAlertView`, it looks like you need to use a weak reference in the block because it may retain the block in an iVar and thus create a retain cycle.

Comment: There is no "extra work" here. On the contrary, the reason this is nice is that you express what you want done on dismissal in a block rather than in a separate delegate method or methods.

Comment: @matt, there certainly is extra work, which is that you need to create `weakPrompt` (which seems small, but it's something you need to carefully consider in every block code you write). It's an unfortunate side effect of how blocks are implemented. It could have been implemented a different way, but it is the way it is. Maybe it's the best way, but C++'s lambdas did it differently, so it's certainly not the only way. But, given how it is, there isn't a really good way around having to declare and use weakPrompt.

Comment: See the answer by @newacct - they make a very good point in their first bullet. Might you be better served by something other than `DTAlertView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In my opinion, a good third-party block-based alert view API, will probably take blocks where the alert view is passed as a parameter, because the original UIAlertView delegate methods pass them. If it is passed as a parameter to the block, then inside the block, it can just use this parameter rather than capture it from the outside. However, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTFoundation/blob/develop/Core/Source/iOS/BlocksAdditions/DTAlertView.h) of `DTAlertView`, its block does not take any parameters.
- If the API does not pass the alert view as a parameter into the block, and you discover that you for some reason need to access the alert view in that block itself, then yes, you will need to capture a weak-reference to the alert view in the block. Otherwise, there will be a retain cycle because: 1) In order for alert view button thing to work, the alert view must retain the block, and 2) If the block has a strong reference to the alert view, there will be a retain cycle.
- In a sense, a block-based API gives you more flexibility than a delegate-based API, because in a block-based API, you the user of the API can decide whether your block has strong or weak references to each thing as you see fit; whereas in a delegate-based API, the API decides whether the delegate reference is weak or strong (usually weak), and the user doesn't control it.

Comment: Nice thorough answer. Someone suggested Cocoanetics DT stuff to me, I'll look around at alternatives. As a former Smalltalk guy, I find I'm thrilled ObjC has blocks, but disappointed about how nuanced they are. In a Smalltalk world, we would have `cull:`'ed the block with the prompt. But the need to type signature the block on ObjC makes that a bummer. If the DTAlertView were designed as you suggest, it would just be pushing the ugly around in my opinion. Then I'd go from simple `^{...;}` to `^(DTAlertView* prompt){...;}`